# React Native How To Paste Image in Input

Tags: image, react-native, clipboard, textinput

I want to be able to paste an image from clipboard into a text input similar to how groupMe, Facebook Messenger, and just about any other chat app allows you to paste an image into their text input.

I have looked at a few different options. The most promising looked to be this [package](https://github.com/Gustash/react-native-image-keyboard) but I am not being able to.

I am working with my project on expo and I am not sure it supports it.

Any clues to being able to do this wold be very helpful.